# Comparar 2 array de objetos

Tags: php

Hola antes que nada agradezco la ayuda de antemano y aclaro que soy algo novato en temas de php, bien pues mi pregunta es la siguiente.

Recibo 2 arrays de objetos y me gustaria comparar un array con el otro tomando como referencia el id de cada objeto de los array y que me regresar los objetos que estan en el array uno y no esten en el array 2

```
$array1 = [
    {
        "id": 275692738,
        "name": "Dispositivo 2 test"
        "lastSeenAt": "Last seen:  2019-05-09"
    },
    {
        "id": 275689630,
        "name": "ONEPLUS A5000",
        "lastSeenAt": "Last seen:  2019-05-09"
    },
    {
        "id": 275690721,
        "name": "herr",
        "lastSeenAt": "Last seen:  2019-05-09"
    },
    {
        "id": 275309414,
        "name": "Firefox",
        "lastSeenAt": "Last seen:  2019-05-08"
    },
    {
        "id": 275366399,
        "name": "Android Panel",
        "lastSeenAt": "Last seen:  2019-05-07"
    }
];

$array2 = [
    {
        "id": 275689630,
        "name": "ONEPLUS A5000",
        "lastSeenAt": "Last seen:  2019-05-09"
    },
    {
        "id": 275690721,
        "name": "herr",
        "lastSeenAt": "Last seen:  2019-05-09"
    }
];
```

En este caso necesito que filtre los valores que estan en el $array2 y me regrese los otros 3 objetos que no se encuentran en el $array2

Lo intente con 2 bucles foreach pero no he podido hacer que me regrese los resultados que busco.

```
foreach($array1 as $obj){

   foreach ($array2 as $obj2) {

       if ($obj2->id != $obj1->id) {

           echo obj1->id

      }     

   }
}
```

Como podria hacer que esto funcione?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que hacer la comparación de igualdad y así sabes que un elemento del primer array se ha encontrado en el segundo, y esos no los devolverás.

Si tus array son {A, B, C, D} y {C, A}, en la primera vuelta del primer foreach te cogera el elemento A, que lo comparará con C (primera vuelta del segundo) y te lo devolverá como que no se encuentra (cosa que no es cierta).

Además tienes que utilizar sentencias que te permitan salir de un bucle, cuando un elemento ya se ha encontrado una vez (así optimizas el código, :-( lo siento pero no conozco php)

En pseudocodigo (nada académico) podría ser:

```
por cada elemento1 de array1
{
    encontrado = falso
    por cada elemento2 de array2
    {
        Si (elemento1 == elemento2) entonces
        {
            encontrado = verdadero
            sal del bucle interior
        }
    }
    Si (encontrado == falso) entonces
    {
        devuelve este elemento1
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo he hecho lo que me sugieres ya que se me hizo el metodomas sencillo y me fue mas facil entender, y me ha funcionado a la perfeccion.

Comment: De todos modos, al existir una función que permite encontrar las diferencias en arrays, me parece mejor respuesta la de phpMyGuel

Answer (score 6):

La estructura que has puesto no compila. Creo que los datos de partida que tienes son realmente un string de objetos JSON.

Para tratar de conseguir una estructura de datos válida planteo dos escenarios:

**Escenario 1**

```
$json1 = '[
    {
        "id": 275692738,
        "name": "Dispositivo 2 test",
        "lastSeenAt": "Last seen:  2019-05-09"
    },
    {
        "id": 275689630,
        "name": "ONEPLUS A5000",
        "lastSeenAt": "Last seen:  2019-05-09"
    },
    {
        "id": 275690721,
        "name": "herr",
        "lastSeenAt": "Last seen:  2019-05-09"
    },
    {
        "id": 275309414,
        "name": "Firefox",
        "lastSeenAt": "Last seen:  2019-05-08"
    },
    {
        "id": 275366399,
        "name": "Android Panel",
        "lastSeenAt": "Last seen:  2019-05-07"
    }
]';

$json2 = '[
    {
        "id": 275689630,
        "name": "ONEPLUS A5000",
        "lastSeenAt": "Last seen:  2019-05-09"
    },
    {
        "id": 275690721,
        "name": "herr",
        "lastSeenAt": "Last seen:  2019-05-09"
    }
]';
```

**Escenario 2**

```
$array1 = [
   array (
        "id" => 275692738,
        "name" => "Dispositivo 2 test",
        "lastSeenAt" => "Last seen:  2019-05-09"
    ),
    array (
        "id" => 275689630,
        "name" => "ONEPLUS A5000",
        "lastSeenAt" => "Last seen:  2019-05-09"
    ),
    array (
        "id" => 275690721,
        "name" => "herr",
        "lastSeenAt" => "Last seen:  2019-05-09"
    ),
    array (
        "id" => 275309414,
        "name" => "Firefox",
        "lastSeenAt" => "Last seen:  2019-05-08"
    ),
    array (
        "id" => 275366399,
        "name" => "Android Panel",
        "lastSeenAt" => "Last seen:  2019-05-07"
    )
];

$array2 = [
    array (
        "id" => 275689630,
        "name" => "ONEPLUS A5000",
        "lastSeenAt" => "Last seen:  2019-05-09"
    ),
    array (
        "id" => 275690721,
        "name" => "herr",
        "lastSeenAt" => "Last seen:  2019-05-09"
    )
];
```

Mi respuesta se basa en el **escenario 1**, que es lo más parecido a la estructura inicial que nos has planteado y para no extenderme demasiado trabajaré solo en esta.

**Respuesta**

```
$array1 = json_decode($json1);
$array2 = json_decode($json2);

$diff = array_udiff($array1, $array2,
    function ($obj_a, $obj_b) {
        return $obj_a->id - $obj_b->id;
    }
);

print_r($diff);
```

Lo que hago es convertir ese `string JSON` de partida en un `array` válido mediante la función `json_decode()` para luego tratarlo con la función `array_udiff()`, que nos permite gestionar la comparación que dará como resultado de retorno lo que no se cumpla. En nuestra caso, al usar el operador **-** estamos pidiendo que se nos devuelva la diferencia entre `$array1` y `$array_2`.

**Referencia:** [array_udiff()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-udiff.php)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta